# Django-CMS add content to the first page

Tags: django, django-cms

## How to add contents to the first Page?

After installing Django-CMS according to the [documentation](https://www.django-cms.org/en/blog/2020/07/07/5-step-django-cms-tutorial-for-new-developers/), starting the docker project, and logged in to Django-CMS, the user is presented with the screen shown below. In the upper right corner there is a button `New Page`.

[image: Screenshot Django-CMS page]

### Clicking on `New Page`

After clicking on `New Page` the user is presented with the form for a New page, as shown below, I added some text.

[image: Screnshot]

### Saving the page and enter the Page Tree

After the form is saved, then Page Tree is shown. Clicking the circle and select `Publish`, and the on the eye, the user is presented with a blank page with the page title correct.

[image: Screenshot Django-CMS]

[image: screenshot]

My question is: **How do I add content to this page?**

#### Template used

For this basic example the minimal template is used, I know this because when I add some place holder text to the template it comes up on the page.

```html
{% load cms_tags sekizai_tags %}
<html>
    <head>
        <title>{% page_attribute "page_title" %}</title>
        {% render_block "css" %}
    </head>
    <body>
        {% cms_toolbar %}
        {% placeholder "content" %}
        {% render_block "js" %}
        <p>Writing this text to find what template is used!</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image: screenshot Django-CMS]

The question is, how do I add contents, probably by adding to the template variable `content`? But how?

The [documentation](http://docs.django-cms.org/_/downloads/en/latest/pdf/) is wishy-washy on this.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer to my question, and since it might be helpful to others I add the solution here.

First, the philosophy behind Django CMS is very different compared to [Mezzanine](http://mezzanine.jupo.org/) and [Wagtail](https://wagtail.io/). There is no page model, instead you add content to plugins, that are placed on the page according to placeholders defined in the template. The layout of the admin panel is also very different.

To add text content to the blank page presented in the question, click on the symbol in the upper right corner as shown below

[image: Screenshot]

Next, click on the `+` icon and choose the text plugin.

[image: Screenshot]

[image: Screenshot]

Add some text and click save.

[image]

Click publish and your page is up.

[image: Screenshot]